# Text Mask Angular 2 For 9 Digit Zipcode

Tags: angular, masking

Using text-mask for a zipcode mask that pops up with a '-' placeholder fater the 5th digit in a zipcode that is 9 digits long.

Need to be able to submit either 5 or 9 digit zips

The problem is when using text mask when I type in 5 characters as the zip, it automatically applies the placeholder so instead of getting:

```
94941
```

I get:

```
94941-
```

Which fails validation, is there anyway to make this package apply the placeholder after I enter the 6th digit?

Thanks,
Adam